# How to download and get values from JSON file using VBScript or batch file?

Tags: json, batch-file, vbscript

This is the VBScript code answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505306/how-to-get-value-from-json-file-to-a-variable) to get the JSON file from computer with proper values.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

json = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\path\to\combined.json").ReadAll

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = """passed"":(true|false),"
re.IgnoreCase = True

For Each m In re.Execute(json)
  passed = CBool(m.SubMatches(0))
Next
```

But I have a JSON file that looks like this which is online,

```
["AA-BB-CC-MAKE-SAME.json","SS-ED-SIXSIX-TENSE.json","FF-EE-EE-EE-WW.json","ZS-WE-AS-FOUR-MINE.json","DD-RF-LATERS-LATER.json","FG-ER-DC-ED-FG.json"]
```

How to download this JSON file and get the values to five variables using either VBScript or batch file?

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28143160/how-can-i-download-a-file-with-batch-file-without-using-any-external-tools   and this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47048992/parse-and-store-text-from-a-json-file-in-windows-batch-script

Comment: Consider using PowerShell for this. You life will become a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example for downloading a json from internet and parse it :

```
Dim http,URL
URL = "http://ip-api.com/json/"
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "GET",URL,False
http.send
strJson = http.responseText

Set j = ParseJson(strJson)
Result = "IP =" & j.query & vbCrlf &_
"ISP = "& j.isp & vbCrlf &_
"Country = "& j.country & vbCrlf &_
"TimeZone = "& j.timezone

Wscript.echo Result
'--------------------------------------------------------
Function ParseJson(strJson)
    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set window = html.parentWindow
    window.execScript "var json = " & strJson, "JScript"
    Set ParseJson = window.json
End Function
'--------------------------------------------------------
```

You can give a try for this code :

```
Dim http,URL
URL = "https://privateURL/jsonfile/"
Set http = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
http.open "GET",URL,False
http.send
strJson = http.responseText
Result = Extract(strJson,"(\x22(.*)\x22)")
Arr = Split(Result,",")
For each Item in Arr
    wscript.echo Item
Next
'******************************************
Function Extract(Data,Pattern)
   Dim oRE,oMatches,Match,Line
   set oRE = New RegExp
   oRE.IgnoreCase = True
   oRE.Global = True
   oRE.Pattern = Pattern
   set oMatches = oRE.Execute(Data)
   If not isEmpty(oMatches) then
       For Each Match in oMatches  
           Line = Line & Trim(Match.Value) & vbCrlf
       Next
       Extract = Line
   End if
End Function
'******************************************
```

Comment: I get this error at line 9 char 1, "Object doesn't support this property or method: 'j.query'. Code 800A01B6"

Comment: @CodenameK You should provide me the real link of your json file to try to parse it correctly, in my example just works for the link in the script !

Comment: Did you get the link?

Comment: It works. Can you change the link in your answer as the link is personal?

Comment: @CodenameK Done ;)

Comment: Do you know [how to get values from JSON file using AppleScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51616761/how-to-get-values-from-json-file-using-applescript)

Comment: new to VBA. im trying to make a call to a webservice and parse the json returned. found this post...but getting error on ```Wscript.echo Result'``` that says ```object doesnt support this property or method```